# Sum of roots: Vietas formulas

Tags: polynomials, roots

The equation $x^4-x^3-1=0$ has roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$. Find the equations with roots $\alpha^6, \beta^6, \gamma^6, \delta^6$. I was able to do this using the substitution $y=x^3$. I obtained the equation $y^4-y^3-3y^2-3y-1=0$ and then applied applied the formula $\sum\alpha^2=(\sum\alpha)^2-2\sum\alpha\beta$ to get $S_6$. The mark schemes mentions an alternative way way which I do not understand.

Here it is. 'Use $S_{n+4}=S_n + S_{n+3}$ ' and then goes on to compute $S_{-1}, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5$ and finally $S_6$ How did they get $S_{n+4}=S_n + S_{n+3}$ in the first place?

Could someone please explain?

Comment: What are the $S_n$?

Comment: $S_n=\alpha^n +\beta^n +\gamma^n +\delta^n$

Comment: But final equation requires also other sums like $\alpha^n\beta^n+\alpha^n\gamma^n+\cdots+\gamma^n\delta^n$, ..., $\alpha^n\beta^n\gamma^n\delta^n$. Isn't it?

Comment: You wrote $S_n + 4 = S_n + S_{n + 3}$ which is equivalent to $S_{n + 3} = 4$.  Is that what you wanted?  Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I guess it's $S_{n + 4} = S_n + S_{n + 3}$!  More Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\alpha^4-\alpha^3-1=0$. If you multiply this by $\alpha^n$ and add the corresponding results for $\beta, \gamma, \delta$ you get what you are looking for.

Note that it is useful to know that $S_0=4$

---

It is easy to add spurious solutions here: what you are looking for is $4$ solutions and therefore a quartic equation.